# Возможно ли достать переменную и функции в классе? python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно переменную из функции в классе первого файла перенести во второй файл. Как это можно сделать?

Пример 1 файла:

```
class get:
    def abc(self):
        if 1 == 1:
            a = 'text'
        else:
            pass
```

Пример 2 файла:

```
from main import *

get = get()
get.abc()
print(a)
```

Не спрашивайте почему код такой странный, так и должно быть.

Comment: Нет, так не должно быть. Перепишите код так, чтобы такой надобности в принципе не возникало.

Comment: @andreymal, предложите как можно переписать код пожалуйста. А то просто написали о том, что так не должно быть и оставили.

Comment: А какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: @andreymal я делаю чат-бота и мне надо сделать возможность выведения температуры в реальном времени. Температура я хотел взять с сайта и решил парсер сделать в другом файле в классе для того, что бы это было похоже на модуль

Comment: Ну так просто сделайте `return a` в функции-парсере и не надо никаких странностей городить, не?

Comment: Поддерживаю @andreymal. `return a`  — лучший вариант

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для получения значения полей объекта класса рекомендуется использовать геттеры.
Ваш вариант:

```
#main.py: 

class get:
def abc(self):
    if 1 == 1:
        self.a = 'text'
    else:
        pass

#1.py:

from main import *
get = get()
get.abc()
print(get.a)
```

Альтернативный вариант:

```
#get.py:

class get:

def __init__(self):
    # установка а при инициализации
    self.a = self.__abc()

# геттер
def get_a(self):
    # какие-нибудь проверки
    return self.a

def __abc(self):
    if 1 == 1:
        return 'text'
    else:
        pass

#1.py:
from get import *

get = get()
a = get.get_a()
print(a)
```

Comment: слишком как-то запарено. это единственный вариант?

Comment: @Dariuz - нет, варианты всегда есть.

Answer (score 0):

Да, в вашем случае вам после `a = 'text'` следует прописать `return a`. Однако после этого функция завершиться, а get() "как бы станет самой переменной": т.е. теперь не `print(a)`, а `print(get())`

И кстати советую имена классов начинать с Большой Буквы, так всегда легко отличить класс от функции, если код был импортирован с другого файла.

Comment: у меня почему то переменная get() не появляется

Comment: @Dariuz,  я сказал "как бы станет самой переменной" для того что бы было легче понять в чём суть. А так это не переменная, а функция которая возвращает переменную a, затем завершается.